# Error running sstabledowngrade with DSE 6.x

Tags: cassandra, ldap, datastax-enterprise

I am facing the following error when running sstabledowngrade :

> Error rewriting
> TrieIndexSSTableReader(path='/cassdata/data/mosaictest/enctab-xxxx/aa-1-bti-Data.db'):
> com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.crypto.KeyAccessException:
> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException:
> Authentication error on host
> vdldsecasdbda15.prvcld.syfbank.com/X.X.X.X:9042: Host
> vdldsecasdbda15.prvcld.syfbank.com/X.X.X.X:9042 requires
> authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration

When I checked the system log, the stacktrace suggests something wrong with ldap config but I don't understand what.

> ERROR [IOThread-12] 2021-01-25 04:23:32,588  LdapUtils.java:293 -
> Either the username or password were null or zero length ERROR [RMI
> TCP Connection(161)-127.0.0.1] 2021-01-25 04:23:47,733
> FileUtils.java:546 - Error while getting
> /cassdata/data/xxx/enctab-xxxxx/snapshots/2
> folder size.
> /cassdata/data/xxx/enctab-xxxxx/snapshots/2